# Select records with latest timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql, database, time, timestamp

I have two tables, from witch want to select the **user, system and soft**.

**soft** records should be the one with  the latest "**tstamp2**"

First: table systems

```
USER       SYSTEM           ltstamp           
======-----======----===================
User1       LA1      2013-05-06 11:27:26
User2       LA2      2013-06-07 11:27:26
```

Second: table software

```
Soft     SYSTEM            tstamp2
=====----=====------===================
  Av1      LA1       2013-04-06 10:27:26
  Av2      LA1       2013-05-06 11:27:26
  Av1      LA2       2013-04-06 10:27:26
  Av2      LA2       2013-06-07 11:27:26
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT s.user, s.system, sw.max_tstamp, sw2.soft
FROM
  systems s INNER JOIN (SELECT system, MAX(tstamp2) AS max_tstamp
                        FROM software
                        GROUP BY system) sw
  ON s.system = sw.system INNER JOIN software sw2
  ON s.system = sw2.system AND sw.max_tstamp=sw2.tstamp2
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bf0b/3).

Answer (score 1):

You need a sub request to do it. For example :

```
select * from systems 
where ltstamp = (select top 1 ltstamp from systems order by ltstamp desc)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

`select user, system,soft , min(tstamp2) tstamp2 from systems s inner join software w on s.SYSTEM=w.SYSTEM group by user`